# How to calculate return when initial value is negative?

Tags: estimation, percentage

Let's say the initial value is A, and A is negative (A<0).

The final value is B, which is positive (B>0).

I know I can not use log returns, since A is negative

So, if I want to calculate the return, I will have to use the formula where

$Return=\frac{Final Value - Initial Value}{Initial Value}=$
$=\frac{B-A}{A}=$
$=\frac{Positive-(-Negative)}{Negative}=\frac{Positive+Positive}{Negative}=Negative$

Which means I will get a negative value in the end, which is not true of course since B (final value) is greater than A (initial value).

Is there some way to deal with this issue?

Comment: I have two dictionaries, and I calculate the percentage of words that belongs in the first and the second, and I subtract these two percentages. This value can be positive (usually) but sometimes it becomes negative, and then I have the problem I describe in my original post.

Comment: Setting Cagdas Ozgenc's questions as to the logic of this metric aside, to me your metric represents a simple difference. Unless there are overriding reasons to preserving the ordering of the texts, why not just take the absolute value of that difference?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc the percentages are the percentages of words that belong to the dictionary, divided by the total number of words in the document. To subtract the two percentages means to get a measure of how many more words of dictionary 1 are in the text versus words of dictionary 2. The reason this difference makes sense is that one dictionary contains "positive" words while the other dictionary contains "negative" words

Comment: @DJohnson I tried just taking the simple difference. It is also something that puzzles me whether I should calculate the percentage return or the simple difference. The main reason is that, quite frankly, the percentage difference seems to better fit my data... Another problem with the difference of percentages that you are suggesting, is that if you go from 1% to 2% it is the same as going from 99% to 100%, which are not realistically equal if I am not mistaken.. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: To your point, both the absolute and relative approaches have weaknesses. Why not create quartiles for each and then cross-classify the results? That would blunt the point made about a 1% difference between 1%-2% and 99%-100% as well as the fact that relative numbers are asymmetric, e.g., the % change from 10% to 15% isn't the same value as the % change from 15% to 10% along with the many well-known limitations of ratio estimators such as the TF-IDF.

Comment: The raw percentage is not significant while the returns are. Only in a few cases do i have the issue with the negative initial values, so i do not think it is a major concern, but it would be nice to deal woth these few cases somehow